# Emacs Segmentation fault

Tags: crash

Since 1 month ago, I have been experiencing this issue. I already tried to launch emacs with `emacs --with-x-toolkit=lucid` But the problem persists, anyone experiencing the same issue?

```
Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault Backtrace: emacs[0x507999]
emacs[0x4ee55c] emacs[0x50613e] emacs[0x506363] emacs[0x5063cf]
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x11da0)[0x7fbbaeb47da0]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a+0x31)[0x7fbbb31fb4d1]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_unref+0x15)[0x7fbbb31da8e5]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x20e04d)[0x7fbbb444804d]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_unref+0x1a2)[0x7fbbb31daa72]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x11afdc)[0x7fbbb4354fdc]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x1681b1)[0x7fbbb43a21b1]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0xb1)[0x7fbbb31d5dc1]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x22622)[0x7fbbb31e8622]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xa75)[0x7fbbb31f0c85]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x8f)[0x7fbbb31f169f]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x39276e)[0x7fbbb45cc76e]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_run_dispose+0x48)[0x7fbbb31dc3d8]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x1681b1)[0x7fbbb43a21b1]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0xb1)[0x7fbbb31d5dc1]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x22622)[0x7fbbb31e8622]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xa75)[0x7fbbb31f0c85]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x8f)[0x7fbbb31f169f]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x39276e)[0x7fbbb45cc76e]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_run_dispose+0x48)[0x7fbbb31dc3d8]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x1681b1)[0x7fbbb43a21b1]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0xb1)[0x7fbbb31d5dc1]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x22622)[0x7fbbb31e8622]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xa75)[0x7fbbb31f0c85]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x8f)[0x7fbbb31f169f]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x39276e)[0x7fbbb45cc76e]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_run_dispose+0x48)[0x7fbbb31dc3d8]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x1681b1)[0x7fbbb43a21b1]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x19d)[0x7fbbb31d5ead]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x22622)[0x7fbbb31e8622]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xa75)[0x7fbbb31f0c85]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x8f)[0x7fbbb31f169f]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x39276e)[0x7fbbb45cc76e]
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_unref+0x133)[0x7fbbb31daa03]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_container_remove+0xa6)[0x7fbbb43a0656]
emacs[0x4e2e51] ... [1]    10803 segmentation fault (core dumped) 
emacs --with-x-toolkit=lucid
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the segfault, but `--with-x-toolkit` is a configure option when building Emacs, not a meaningful runtime option.

Comment: (See the Emacs [build/installation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/INSTALL) and [command line arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Invocation.html) documentation for further clarification on my previous comment.)

Comment: You might want to try `emacs -nw` in an xterm or a console. That should stay away from gtk and *may* avoid the segfault. If that works fine, it is more likely IMO that the fault lies with gtk (or one of the libraries that it depends on) than with emacs itself. You might want to [submit a bug report](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bugs.html#Bugs) and include all the information that you have not included here - what OS, what version, what version of gtk, what version of emacs, etc. FWIW, I'm running emacs 26.0.50 on Fedora 24 and I have not seen segfault.

Comment: Did you heavily customize your desktop appearence? I've seen some other programs crash on GTK with poorly implemented themes.

Comment: Mmm I guess not, I just configure my window manager i3... I was using emacs 25, I just upgraded it to see if the problems persists...

Comment: A crash indicates an Emacs bug, especially if you can reproduce it from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Please consider reporting the bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem: in the segfault message, I had a line mentioning the file `/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0`.

I found that the problem was related to the use of the Linum package. I had

```
'(global-linum-mode t)
```

in my init file. The segfault disappeared after commenting this line (or deactivating `linum-mode`).